# Drupal 7: active main menu when click menu block's menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have 3 content type

HTML
HTML4
HTML5

2 menu block
HTML4
HTML5

In my main menu have 2 menu links (HOME | HTML)

HTML4 (menu block) show the contents of HTML4 (content type).

I configured the HTML4 and HTML5 (2 menu block) should be appear when user click the HTML (main menu). It is fine.

My question is : how to active(highlighting) HTML(main menu) when the user click a link from the HTML4 or HTML5 (2 menu block) ?

Solution : I found the module name is "menu position" http://drupal.org/project/menu_position.
This module make relationship between the main menu and content type.

Comment: Are the HTML 4 and 5 menus children of main menu or separate menus altogether? If you make them children and then use the menu block module to create blocks from the children rather than blocks from individual menus they will be part of the active trail

Comment: @BenSwinburne The HTML4 and HTML5 menus are not the child menu of main menu. Those 2 are separated menu. But those 2 menus are relationship with 2 content type (HTML4 n HTML5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to do that:

1> make sure you are using your own theme.

2> Write the css for the menu to highlight when one clicks inside.

### To Know when the child of the menu is clicked

Use `jQuery` to check for the children being clicked and add the highlight class to the menu name using  $('#MenuDiv').addClass('highlightClass');

If you post code of your menu, maybe I can help from jQuery point of view.